# lable not visible while scrolltofirsterror antd forms

Tags: reactjs, next.js, antd

[image]

when scrolling to first error, only the field and error message is visible. is there a way to add an offset so the label is visible too?

```
 <Form
          form={form}
          name="addBasicProjectInfo"
          onFinish={onFinish}
          autoComplete="off"
          layout="vertical"
          colon={false}
          className="flex flex-col gap-7"
          scrollToFirstError
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a configuration to the `scrollToFirstError` prop. The API is similar to [scroll-into-view-if-needed](https://github.com/scroll-into-view/scroll-into-view-if-needed), as that is what Ant form uses under the hood.

In this instance you may need something like following.

```
scrollToFirstError: {
    block: 'center',
    behavior: 'smooth',
    scrollMode: 'if-needed',
    boundary: (parent) => !parent.classList.contains({scroll-container-class}),
}
```

It's important to manually define the `boundary` when we use `block: 'center'`, in order to prevent any unpredicted scrolling in the view-port. You can read more about `boundary` in [here](https://github.com/scroll-into-view/compute-scroll-into-view#boundary).